# How to configure NGinx to point wildcard style urls back to the same filesystem path

Tags: nginx

I'd like to use a section of the url to help with cache busting and tracking versions of resources being used in my application

That is to say that I've got a web app that has it's resources kept separate and served by nginx.  The resources are kept in folders:

```
app_name/img/sprites.png
app_name/css/compressed.css
app_name/scripts/mini.app.js
```

I'd like to then refer to these with uris of the form:

```
/app_name/#{version}/img/sprites.png
```

or perhaps

```
/#{version}/app_name/img/sprites.png
```

where #{version} is version of the resources to load.

I'd then want to always keep the resources in the same spot in the filesystem and use nginx to always point back to the same files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you just want those three subdirs, and return a 404 if the resource isn't found, you can do this with a [regex location](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) and a [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files):

```
# /app_name/#{version}/img/sprites.png urls:
location ~ ^/app_name/[^/]+(?<resource>/(img|css|scripts)/.+) {
  try_files /app_name$resource =404;
}

# /#{version}/app_name/img/sprites.png urls:
location ~ ^/[^/]+(?<resource>/app_name/(img|css|scripts)/.+) {
  try_files $resource =404;
}
```

If you want the locations to match any dir instead of just the three listed, you can replace (img|css|scripts) with [^/]+.

Comment: Several things: any instance of # in the config file needs to be in quotes or it will turn the rest of the line into a comment. I'm fairly certain that the # in the question was part of the variable declaration, and not a literal # (url fragments aren't generally sent to the server). .* is greedy, so $version would end up with everything except the last component of the url path. The rewrite is unnecessary, you already know which file you want to serve, you should just serve it. Finally, it doesn't address both possibilities that he suggested, only the first (and it doesn't actually do that).

Comment: I think that this is the approach that I prefer. Thanks for the examples and the links to the docs.